# Ansible не выполняет "command:" в docker

Tags: linux, docker, администрирование, ansible

host: ubuntu 18.04

ansible: 2.9.20

docker-ce: 5:20.10.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic

```yaml
    - name: test container
      when:
        - ansible_system == 'Linux'
        - ansible_architecture == 'x86_64'
      become: yes
      docker_container:
        name: test-01
        hostname: ansible-ubuntu-20-04
        image: diodonfrost/ansible-ubuntu:20.04
        volumes:
          - /tmp/roles:/root/.ansible/roles
        output_logs: yes
        state: started
        command: touch /tmp/1
        interactive: yes
        tty: yes
```

Виртуалка с убунтой, в ней докер, в контейнерах планируется тестить код (абсолютная песочница). Всё создаётся и даже запускается, но результата как-то не вижу. Т.е. `touch /tmp/1` висит, но не выполняется:

```bsh
root@docker-test-01:~# docker container ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
fc82da6238a4   diodonfrost/ansible-ubuntu:20.04   "/sbin/init touch /tmp/1…"   6 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds             test-01
```

```bsh
root@docker-test-01:~# docker container exec test-01 ls /tmp/
hsperfdata_root
root@docker-test-01:~#
```

Запуск из хоста - всё прекрасно отрабатывает:

```bsh
root@docker-test-01:~# docker container exec -i -t test-01 touch /tmp/1
root@docker-test-01:~# docker container exec test-01 ls /tmp/
1
hsperfdata_root
root@docker-test-01:~#
```

Куда копать?

**UPD**. В ответ на комент:

```bsh
root@docker-test-01:~# docker container ps -a --format "{{ .Command }}"
"/sbin/init w"
```

Не, после - тишина.

Comment: то, что написано в столбце «command», явно несколько длиннее, чем приведено. там, видимо, содержимое cmd или entrypoint спряталось.

Comment: Поискал как вывести более подробно, не нашёл, но зато поменял выполняемую комманду на `w`.

Comment: вероятно, [вот этот entrypoint](https://github.com/diodonfrost/docker-ansible/blob/master/ubuntu-ansible/Dockerfile.ubuntu-20.04#L25) надо игнорировать с помощью [entrypoint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/docker_container_module.html#parameters)

Comment: УУУ!!! Поехало! Оформи ответ, я плюсану.

Comment: и что я буду писать? я этот ансибль никогда в глаза не видел. у кого ансибль есть, тому и карты в руки!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, готово. Спасибо ещё раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [@aleksandr barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin) за пинок в нужную сторону.

Т.к. стоит задача не просто запускать какой-то код, а запускать именно с целью посмотреть работает он или нет, то было бы неплохо, чтобы нам возвращался именно тот exit, который есть на самом деле. Вот комбинация параметров, которая делает то, что надо:

Тут идёт перезапись `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]` из [оригинального](https://github.com/diodonfrost/docker-ansible/blob/0f353041531670e3036bfb45e3501ab8e9635299/ubuntu-ansible/Dockerfile.ubuntu-20.04#L25) файла нашей командой `curl`. В `command`, который является обёрткой над [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) передаём параметры к `curl` и обязательно не забываем про `detach: no`. Без него ничего работать не будет:

```yaml
- name: Create test container
  when:
    - ansible_system == 'Linux'
    - ansible_architecture == 'x86_64'
  become: yes
  docker_container:
    name: test-01
    hostname: ansible-ubuntu-20-04
    image: diodonfrost/ansible-ubuntu:20.04
    volumes:
      - /tmp/roles:/root/.ansible/roles
    state: started
    entrypoint: curl
    command: --fail --head "http://example.com/123"
    detach: no
```

Т.к. файла\каталога `123` нет - сервер нам вернёт `404`, `--fail` скажет `curl`'у НЕ возвращать `exit 0`, а вернуть `exit 22`, а `detach: no` не будет превращать любой `exit` от команды в `exit 0` самого ансибла. Получаем:

```
    "msg": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found\n", 
    "status": 22
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
docker-test-01.local       : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

А вот если поменять `command: --fail --head "http://example.com/123` на `command: --fail --head "http://example.com/`, то `index.html` на сервере будет, нам везде вернут `exit 0` и выхлоп ансибла будет соответствующий:

```
            "volumes_from": null, 
            "working_dir": null
        }
    }
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
docker-test-01.local       : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```